# How to use C# attributes to select a method in a class based on a string?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
public class MyMethods
{

    [SpecialMethod("test")]
    public string GetTestString(int i)
    {
        return string.Format("Hello world {0} times!",i);
    }

    [SpecialMethod("lorem")]
    public string GetSomeLoremIpsumText(int i)
    {
        // ignores the 'i' variable
        return "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
    }

    // ... more methods with the same signature here ...

    public string DefaultMethod(int i)
    {
        return "The default method happened! The attribute wasn't found.";
    }

    public string ThisMethodShouldNotShowUpViaAttributes(int i)
    {
        return "You should not be here.";
    }
}
```

I also have defined the attribute simply like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class SpecialMethodAttribute : System.Attribute 
{
    private string _accessor;
    public string Accessor 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _accessor;
        }
    }
    public SpecialMethodAttribute(string accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
    }
}
```

What I want to be able to do might look like this:

```
public class MethodAccessViaAttribute
{
    private MyMethods _m;

    public MethodAccessViaAttribute()
    {
        _m = new MyMethods();
    }

    public string CallMethodByAccessor(string accessor, int i)
    {
        // this is pseudo-code, expressing what I want to be able to do.
        Func<int, string> methodToCall = FindAMethodByAttribute(_m, accessor);
        if (methodToCall == null)
            return _m.DefaultMethod(i);
        else
            return methodToCall(i);
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        // should print "Hello world 3 times!"
        Console.WriteLine(CallMethodByAccessor("test",3));

        // should print "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
        Console.WriteLine(CallMethodByAccessor("lorem",int.MaxValue));

        // should print "The default method happened! The attribute wasn't found."
        Console.WriteLine(CallMethodByAccessor("I-do-not-exist",0));
    }
}
```

Notice that all methods using the `SpecialMethod` attribute follow the same method signature. Ideally, the search function would exclude methods not matching the signature, since a `try/catch` could be used to test if the method matches the `Func` signature.

Can I get a point in the right direction for how to accomplish this?

Comment: It sounds to me like you should rethink this approach. You might as well stick a switch case inside a single method based on the "accessor" word. You could accomplish this in a few different ways other than attributes. I am curious, what's the use case for such code?

Comment: I'm writing a library that I would want to be able to import into another project. Therefore hardcoding the cases is not acceptable. I would want to be able to add a new possible method simply by adding a new method with the correct signature and the appropriate attribute. Since .NET's own unit testing basically uses an approach like this, marking methods that should be called with [TestMethod], I assume there's a way to accomplish this.

Comment: I suggest you look into interfaces (think plugin pattern). What I would do is create an interface to represent the object that implements the method in question. I can then load the assembly and look for classes that implement this interface, instantiate them and call the method.

Comment: Wouldn't that require creating an entire class per method? The idea is that you would write a class with all of the methods you want to expose to my library, and you would decorate each method with the attribute so the library can find and execute it. Suggesting writing an entire class per method would at least be a little ugly in code, but also could have implementation issues with e.g. instance variables.

Comment: The risk is that if you come up with an innovative way to do something that seems to save a few lines of code, no one else who has to maintain the code will be able to understand what it's doing or why. You'll come back to it yourself in a few months and you'll have a hard time with it too.

Comment: If you insist on having a single class with methods, simply inspect the methods looking for the attribute, check against the accessor name and fire accordingly.

Comment: I should have been more specific. The use case is that the string specifying the method comes from an outside source, not from a developer inside C#. So I need to somehow be able to select the method based on string. Huge switch/case blocks are also error prone and attributes, while it could be argued are syntactically sugary, are certainly more readable and maintainable than huge switch/case blocks when it comes time to add a new method to the pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did figure out how to accomplish this task.

I created a class which all classes that contain methods will inherit from. I then created a private method which actually extract and create `Func` objects.

We need a method which will search for any method that has the desired attribute. Reflection has a `MethodInfo` class which represents a method. We can use some LINQ to search all of the methods on the class. We then use a little expression tree fun to generate the `Func` object that will actually call the method on this specific instance of the class:

```
// Locates a method on this class that has the SpecialMethod attribute of the given name
private Func<int, string> FindMethodByAccessor(string accessor)
{
    // Find all methods containing the attribute
    var desiredMethod = this.GetType().GetMethods()
              .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SpecialMethod), false).Length > 0)
              .Where(y => (y.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SpecialMethod), false).First() as SpecialMethod).Accessor == accessor)
              .FirstOrDefault();

    if (desiredMethod == null) return null;

    // This parameter is the first parameter passed into the method. In this case it is an int.    
    ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
    // This parameter refers to the instance of the class. 
    ConstantExpression instance = Expression.Constant(this);
    // This generates a piece of code and returns it in a Func object. We effectively are simply calling the method.
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<int, string>>(
        Expression.Call(instance, desiredMethod, new Expression[] { x }), x).Compile();

}
```

The idea of expression trees is still new to me, but this function does exactly what I want - it will locate a method on the instance of the class it's running in which has been decorated with the given attribute and return it as a `Func` object.

We can now finish the method which actually calls the other methods:

```
public string CallMethodByAccessor(string accessor, int i)
{
    Func<int, string> methodToCall = FindMethodByAccessor(accessor);

    if (methodToCall == null)
        return DefaultMethod(i);
    else
        return methodToCall(i);
}

public string DefaultMethod(int i) { return "Unknown method requested!"; }
```

I still have not added checking to see whether the method with the attribute matches the necessary signature, but that could easily be done by working with properties on the `MethodInfo` object.

Finally, we wrap all this up in a class, which any other class can inherit from. The subclass then implements methods following the signature and decorates them with the attribute. To call the desired method by name, you simply call `CallMethodByAccessor`.

---

To respond finally to all of the suggestions to use a different methodology, I respect all of your ideas and, if the use case were different, this would absolutely be overkill and unnecessary. The specific use case at hand involves a Web service which users and developers can configure. The Web service lets a user specify one or more "endpoints". The endpoint in this case is merely a string. The library I am writing receives data from the Web service, and one of the parameters is the desired "endpoint" string. The idea is that the user could write endpoints as methods, give them any function name they desire, and then associate them with the actual endpoint text via the attribute. For example:

```
[Endpoint("user.login")]
public string performLogin(string credentialString)
{
    // ...
}
```

Since the endpoint name is `user.login` we cannot simply name a class method with that name. Additionally, even if we did, we would still need to use reflection to dig into the class, extract the correct method, and generate a `Func` object to call the method. So, in this instance, using attributes simply makes development far easier, because the only alternative would be using a switch/case block that would have to be rigorously maintained. I feel it would be far more easy for a developer to "forget" to add another `case` block, or to forget to remove a `case` block which is no longer needed, than it would be to mess up the attributes. The attribute "ties" the endpoint name to the method, rather than having to keep track of both the method name and the endpoint name in a totally different block of code.

Finally, the "default" method is absolutely useful in this case. If a user instructs the Web service to call an endpoint which doesn't exist, the app can return a sensible response, e.g. "The endpoint 'MyEendpoint' does not exist." This would be much easier to debug than simply seeing the API crash!

Answer (score 0):

I don't like giving "do this instead" answers, but I can't put this inside a comment.

Instead of this, along with all of the supporting code to handle the attributes

```
public void Test()
{
    Console.WriteLine(CallMethodByAccessor("test",3));
    Console.WriteLine(CallMethodByAccessor("lorem",int.MaxValue));
    Console.WriteLine(CallMethodByAccessor("I-do-not-exist",0));
}
```

This code does the exact same thing:

```
public void Test()
{
    var methods = new MyMethods();
    Console.WriteLine(methods.GetTestString("test", 3));
    Console.WriteLine(methods.GetSomeLoremIpsumText("lorem", int.MaxValue));
}
```

The language is designed on purpose so that if a method doesn't exist, you can't call it. That helps us avoid mistakes at runtime. We don't want our application to execute something or ignore it based on whether or not we spelled a method name correctly. Someone could pull their hair out for hours trying to figure out why the application isn't working and then realize that it's because they misspelled "lorem." Just calling methods the "normal" way prevents all of that. If you misspell a method name then Visual Studio will show an error, the code won't compile, and it's super easy to find and fix. (Plus Intellisense/autocomplete will even help us see the methods that are available.)

Also, if you right-click on a method then Visual Studio will take you right to that method. With the string attributes someone has to follow a lot more code just to figure out which method is actually getting called. And if they need to debug and step through it, they need to step through all that extra stuff.

It's extremely common to have a bunch of classes that each implement the same interface and each have one method. It's good design to have fewer methods - even one - in an interface. (See [Interface Segregation Principle](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/766045/Interface-Segregation-Principle-ISP-of-SOLID-in-Cs).) No one will consider that "ugly." But if we invent our own way of doing it we can really confuse other developers who work on the same code, and it can be challenging to maintain even for the person who wrote it.

Comment: The lesson I maybe should learn is to be more specific about use case. In this particular situation, my library receives requests from a Web service. The Web service allows another developer to specify "endpoints". The dev could specify one or five hundred endpoints. I want the developer in C# to be able to implement those endpoints and easily "indicate" which method belongs to which endpoint by the attribute. Very much like how Web API itself lets you use `[Route("/my/end/point")]`. That said, I think I have a solution based on experimentation and if it works I will post my own answer.